# a singly linked list for all data types, implement insertion, delete and find an element in C language

Tags: c, linked-list

so i have managed to come up with a syntax for only integers. how do i write the syntax for all data types most preferrably using `typedef` and `void*` as well would like to know now to use the `void push_back` command.?

it creates a linked list, adds nodes, deletes nodes and finds any nodes with in the list.
The first node is always made accessible through a global ‘head’ pointer. This pointer is adjusted when first node is deleted.
Similarly there is a ‘curr’ pointer that contains the last node in the list. This is also adjusted when last node is deleted.
Whenever a node is added to linked list, it is always checked if the linked list is empty then add it as the first node.

Is there anyother way to add,delete and find nodes in a linked list without using `#include<stdbool.h>` ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

struct test_struct
{
    int val;
    struct test_struct *next;
};

struct test_struct *head = NULL;
struct test_struct *curr = NULL;

struct test_struct* create_list(int val)
{
    printf("\n creating list with headnode as [%d]\n",val);
    struct test_struct *ptr = (struct test_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct test_struct));
    if(NULL == ptr)
    {
        printf("\n Node creation failed \n");
        return NULL;
    }
    ptr->val = val;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    head = curr = ptr;
    return ptr;
}

struct test_struct* add_to_list(int val, bool add_to_end)
{
    if(NULL == head)
    {
        return (create_list(val));
    }

    if(add_to_end)
        printf("\n Adding node to end of list with value [%d]\n",val);
    else
        printf("\n Adding node to beginning of list with value [%d]\n",val);

    struct test_struct *ptr = (struct test_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct test_struct));
    if(NULL == ptr)
    {
        printf("\n Node creation failed \n");
        return NULL;
    }
    ptr->val = val;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    if(add_to_end)
    {
        curr->next = ptr;
        curr = ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->next = head;
        head = ptr;
    }
    return ptr;
}

struct test_struct* search_in_list(int val, struct test_struct **prev)
{
    struct test_struct *ptr = head;
    struct test_struct *tmp = NULL;
    bool found = false;

    printf("\n Searching the list for value [%d] \n",val);

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        if(ptr->val == val)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    if(true == found)
    {
        if(prev)
            *prev = tmp;
        return ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

int delete_from_list(int val)
{
    struct test_struct *prev = NULL;
    struct test_struct *del = NULL;

    printf("\n Deleting value [%d] from list\n",val);

    del = search_in_list(val,&prev);
    if(del == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(prev != NULL)
            prev->next = del->next;

        if(del == curr)
        {
            curr = prev;
        }
        else if(del == head)
        {
            head = del->next;
        }
    }

    free(del);
    del = NULL;

    return 0;
}

void print_list(void)
{
    struct test_struct *ptr = head;

    printf("\n -------Printing list Start------- \n");
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n [%d] \n",ptr->val);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n -------Printing list End------- \n");

    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0, ret = 0;
    struct test_struct *ptr = NULL;

    print_list();

    for(i = 5; i<10; i++)
        add_to_list(i,true);

    print_list();

    for(i = 4; i>0; i--)
        add_to_list(i,false);

    print_list();

    for(i = 1; i<10; i += 4)
    {
        ptr = search_in_list(i, NULL);
        if(NULL == ptr)
        {
            printf("\n Search [val = %d] failed, no such element found\n",i);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n Search passed [val = %d]\n",ptr->val);
        }

        print_list();

        ret = delete_from_list(i);
        if(ret != 0)
        {
            printf("\n delete [val = %d] failed, no such element found\n",i);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n delete [val = %d]  passed \n",i);
        }

        print_list();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a linked list of different data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131313/is-it-possible-to-have-a-linked-list-of-different-data-types)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyother way to add,delete and find nodes in a linked list without using `#include<stdbool.h>` ?

Yes, don't use any bool types in your code.

Comment: How can I change to my code to accept all data types and not only integers?

Comment: That's a bit tricky, instead of storing int data you would store void* to the data.  That adds extra complications around managing the life times of the objects pointed to and you may need to keep track of which data types were in which nodes.  If you leave that later bit up to the caller, then they could simply decide that their list will contain only one type and the problem is then moot.  See @AlexandreDupriez 's comment to your OP.