# Get and Set Values of different datatype using template on C++

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

Being on a similar condition of [Handling different datatypes in a single structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102853/handling-different-datatypes-in-a-single-structure)
I have an implementation using union, but as it takes the highest variable type as its memory size, I end up allocating 64-bit even for an 8-bit variable type. Also I was writing several functions to get/set values on a specific data type.

Example:

```
class CDataType {

public:
    void setTBOOL8(bool src) {
        m_uAnyData.um_Bool = src;
    }

void setTUINT8(uint8_t src) { //also used for FzrteByte
    m_uAnyData.um_UInt8 = src;
}

......

bool getTBOOL8() const {
    return (m_uAnyData.um_Bool);
}

uint8_t getTUINT8() const { //also used for FzrteByte
    return (m_uAnyData.um_UInt8);
}

.......
private:
    union uAnyData {
        bool     um_Bool;
        uint8_t  um_Byte;
        uint16_t um_Word;
        uint32_t um_DWord;
        uint64_t um_LWord;

    uint8_t  um_UInt8;
    uint16_t um_UInt16;
    uint32_t um_UInt32;
    uint64_t um_UInt64;

    int8_t   um_Int8;
    int16_t  um_Int16;
    int32_t  um_Int32;
    int64_t  um_Int64;

    float  um_Float;
    double um_DFloat;
};

uAnyData m_uAnyData;
};
```

So I was looking for alternate solution using template

```
class CDataType {
public:
    virtual void get() = 0;
}

template<class T> MyDataType public CDataType{
private:
    private T data_;

public:
    MyVariantType(T data) {
        data_ = data;
    }

    virtual T get() {
        return data_;
    }
}

CDataType* var = new MyDataType<int>(100);
var->get();
var = new MyDataType<string>("hello world");
var->get();
```

Comment: what do you actually want to do with it?

Comment: _"So I was looking for alternate solution using template"_ You would need specializations depending on a discriminating template parameter for the actual type (e.g. an enum).

Comment: checkout `boost:variant`

Comment: @xaxxon: I have a user defined memory map data. The user can select any offset and define a datatype to that. based on all the inputs I need to create a data structure and use it on my runtime. Then when user wants to set/get any data, i need to use the data structure for this.

Comment: @kar A `union` doesn't have _offsets_.

Comment: What I think you're trying to say is "I want the user to be able to interpret a spot in memory as any data type they'd like"?  Yes, that is a good use for a template, not a union.  So instead of a union, you just use a parameterized type T.   If you have any specific questions about how to use a template, you should modify your question to put that in there.

Comment: @xaxxon: I have a data map which contains 8 to 128 bytes. As the user sees value in decimal format, he really need to know the exact value in string format. For example representation of float on memory and the actual value that could be seen. For instance if we have 8 bytes of data represented as 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08, on my UI user can select offset 1 which has data 02 and request to create a data type float. so I need to take the data 02 03 04 05 (float - 4 bytes) and create a float data type and show him the actual string value.

Comment: I don't quite know what "the actual string value" means, but this sounds reasonable to use a template.   So what is your specific question about how to use templates?

Comment: ex: if a float value is "3.14". but the representation of this float value will be different on memory right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so clear about what you want, but from one of your comments, it seems like this might be useful. (Or at least you might get some ideas from the
code.)

The TPun class is pointed at some location in memory, either with a pointer or reference to an object, and it allows you to read values from arbitrary offsets from the start of the buffer.

Look at the demonstration at the in `main()` (at the bottom) to see how it can be used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstddef>

class TPun {
    const void* pbuffer;
    template <typename IT>
    const void* offset_ptr(IT byte_offset) const {
        return static_cast<const void*>(static_cast<const char*>(pbuffer) + byte_offset);
    }
public:
    TPun() : pbuffer(nullptr) {}

    template <typename T>
    TPun(const T* pbuffer) : pbuffer(static_cast<const void*>(pbuffer)) {}
    template <typename T>
    TPun(T* pbuffer) : pbuffer(static_cast<const void*>(pbuffer)) {}
    template <typename T>
    TPun(const T& struct_obj) : pbuffer(static_cast<const void*>(&struct_obj)) {}

    template <typename T>
    TPun& operator = (const T* pbuf) { pbuffer = static_cast<const void*>(pbuf); return *this; }
    template <typename T>
    TPun& operator = (T* pbuf) { pbuffer = static_cast<const void*>(pbuf); return *this; }
    template <typename T>
    TPun& operator = (const T& struct_obj) { pbuffer = static_cast<const void*>(&struct_obj); return *this; }

    template <typename T>
    struct is_cchar_ptr {
        template <typename U> static U& dval();
        static int test(char const * const &) { return true; }
        template <typename U>
        static char test(const U&) { return false; }
        static const bool value = sizeof(int) == sizeof(test(dval<T>()));
    };

    // Returns a reference for non-pointer types (only used for const char*)
    template <typename T> struct cptr_pass           { static const T& get(const void* p) { return *static_cast<const T*>(p); } };
    template <typename T> struct cptr_pass<const T*> { static const T* get(const void* p) { return static_cast<const T*>(p); } };

    // at only works for POD types or classes consisting of only POD members
    template <typename T, typename IT>
    T at(IT byte_offset) const {
        if(is_cchar_ptr<T>::value) {
            // special handling when T is const char*
            // returns a pointer to the buffer instead of a pointer created from buffer data
            // using char to access the buffer avoids the strict aliasing rule
            return cptr_pass<T>::get(offset_ptr(byte_offset));
        }
        T value;
        std::memcpy(&value, offset_ptr(byte_offset), sizeof(T));
        return value;
    }

    // This version of at() works with any type, but sports Undefined Behavior,
    // because it violates the strict aliasing rule.
    // This can also cause problems if the offset you give, along with the buffer's
    // base address result in a pointer which is not aligned properly for the type.
    template <typename T, typename IT>
    const T& the_at_of_many_dangers(IT byte_offset) {
        return *static_cast<const T&>(offset_ptr(byte_offset));
    }

    std::ostream& manipulate(std::ostream& is) { return is; }

    template<typename M, typename ...Ms>
    std::ostream& manipulate(std::ostream& is, const M& manipulator, Ms ...manips) {
        return manipulate(is << manipulator, manips...);
    }

    template <typename T, typename IT, typename ...Ms>
    std::string string_at(IT byte_offset, Ms ...manips) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        manipulate(ss, manips...) << at<T>(byte_offset);
        return ss.str();
    }
};

void no_warning_strcpy(char* d, const char* s) { while(*(d++) = *(s++)) {} }

struct test_struct {
    char text[10];
    float number;
    int   some_int;
    double a_double;
    test_struct() {
        no_warning_strcpy(text, "hi there");
        number = 52.25;
        some_int = 1000000000;
        a_double = 1.2e-14;
    }
};


int main() {
    using std::cout;
    using std::string;
    // create a test_struct (values are filled in automatically)
    test_struct ts;
    // copy ts's memory image to a char buffer
    char* memory_buffer = new char[sizeof(ts)];
    std::memcpy(memory_buffer, &ts, sizeof(ts));
    // Create a TPun object, start off pointing at the char buffer
    TPun tpun(memory_buffer);
    // send some field values to cout
    // the "offsetof" macro (defined in  <cstddef>) gives the 
    // byte offset of a field in a struct
    cout << tpun.at<const char*>(offsetof(test_struct, text)) << '\n';
    cout << tpun.at<float>(offsetof(test_struct, number)) << '\n';
    // format a value into a string.  Optionally, add extra ostream manipulator arguments.
    // This makes a string with the data from some_int, and formats it as a hex string
    string hex_string = tpun.string_at<int>(offsetof(test_struct, some_int),  std::hex);
    cout << hex_string << '\n';
    // I screwed this one up -- I used the text field's data to make an int
    // Using the manipulator this way, instead of going directly through
    // cout, keeps cout's flags intact
    cout << tpun.string_at<int>(offsetof(test_struct, text), std::hex) << '\n';
    // change a_double in the original struct
    ts.a_double = -1;
    // tpun is pointing at the buffer copy, so it shows the original value
    cout << tpun.at<double>(offsetof(test_struct, a_double)) << '\n';
    // tpun's target can be chaged on-the-fly like this, and it can be set to
    // view an object's memory directly, without creating a pointer.
    tpun = ts;
    // outputs -1
    cout << tpun.at<double>(offsetof(test_struct, a_double)) << '\n';
}
```

This demo prints:

```
hi there
52.25
3b9aca00
74206968
1.2e-14
-1
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a little